# How to draw an ellipse on Image control without Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an app in C# WF, where user move and zoom image. I want to draw ellipse on Image control because ellipse remains in place, and don't moves when I modify the image.

View:

```
 <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="cavRoot" Opacity="1">
            <Image Name="highresmap4" Source="highresmap4.png" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="1473" Height="770">

            </Image>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Model:

```
class draw
            {
                public static void circle(double x, double y, int width, int height, Canvas cv)
                {

                    Ellipse circle = new Ellipse()
                    {
                        Width = width,
                        Height = height,
                        Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                        StrokeThickness = 6
                    };

                    cv.Children.Add(circle);

                    circle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)x);
                    circle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)y);
                }
            }
```

ViewModel:

```
draw.circle(x, y, 10, 10, cavRoot);
```

Comment: So you want the ellipse to stay in place relative to the form while you pan around the image?

Comment: @DavidG I want the ellipse to stay in place relative to the image.

Comment: how do you do the zooming and panning? You need to bind the ellipse size and position to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the `Image` in a `Grid` and use the `Margin` property of the `Ellipse` to specify its position within the `Image`:

```
public static void circle(double x, double y, int width, int height, Panel cv)
{
    Ellipse circle = new Ellipse()
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        Stroke = Brushes.Red,
        StrokeThickness = 6,
        Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0)
    };
    cv.Children.Add(circle);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="theGrid">
    <Image Name="highresmap4" Source="highresmap4.png" Width="1473" Height="770" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but how i can remove or replace canvas from static void?

Comment: @FredPerry: Just change the type the parameter to `Panel` and call the method with a reference to the `Grid` named `theGrid` in my edited example, e.g.: `draw.circle(x, y, 10, 10, theGrid);`